# Addition with _Bool type in C

Tags: c, boolean

In a piece of code I'm working on, I need to add 1 to an `unsigned long` if some `_Bool` is true.

I've been using

```
unsigned long l;
_Bool b;
... //stuff happens to both variables
if(b)
    ++l;
```

But I read in the C standard that the `_Bool` type is classified as one of the "standard unsigned integer types" and it is guaranteed to express true as 1 and false as 0.

I replaced my code with this seemingly equivalent expression

```
unsigned long l;
_Bool b;
... //stuff happens to both variables
l+=b;
```

My compiler didn't complain and it seems to be working beautifully.

Is this guaranteed to work, or am I just exploiting the implementation of _Bool in my compiler?

Comment: guaranteed to work

Comment: You're not guaranteed to always have "_Bool" ... But if you do, your code will work.  If you don't, it won't even compile :)  Q: Why are you doing integer arithmetic with "true/false"?  Doesn't that pretty much defeat the purpose of having a "_Bool" in the first place????

Comment: @paulsm4 C99 and later absolutely guarantees the existence of `_Bool`. The only way you won't have it is if you have a non-conforming compiler or one that conforms to C90. Such compilers are rare these days. There might be some for small embedded systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *almost* guaranteed to work.

The standard doesn't quite say that a `_Bool` object can only hold the values 0 and 1. And in fact `sizeof(_Bool)` is at least 1, which means it has at least 8 bits, which means that it can in principle hold at least 256 distinct values.

If your code that assigned a value to `b` is reasonably sane, you can safely assume its value is either 0 or 1. All conversions from other types to `_Bool` are guaranteed to yield a value of 0 or 1.

But you can store a value other than 0 or 1 in a `_Bool` object, though any method of doing so is likely to have undefined behavior.

An example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    _Bool b;
    char c = 42;
    memcpy(&b, &c, 1);
    long n = 0;
    n += b;
    printf("n = %ld\n", n);
}
```

The output on my system is

```
n = 42
```

But as long as you don't do silly things like this, and treat `_Bool` with some minimal respect, you should be ok.

Comment: Why the heck would you `memcpy` ONY BYTE?

Comment: @user14107922 -- because `b` is a `_Bool`. With `b = c` there would be an implicit conversion, and `b` would get the value `1`. But the point of the example was that it is possible to store values _other_ than `0` or `1` in a `_Bool`. You might also note the parting: "_...as long as you don't do silly things like this,...._"

Comment: @exnihilo Is there a more efficient way to avoid an implicit version other than making a `memcpy` call to one byte?

Comment: @user14107922 -- this isn't my answer, so you should probably ask the poster. But, `memcpy` is quite efficient, and how else would you copy a value while avoiding assignment?

Comment: I see that @user14107922 no longer has an account, but I'll answer anyway. You probably wouldn't `memcpy` one byte, though you might `memcpy` **N** bytes where **NN* just happens to be 1. But the point was that it's possible to write code that will very likely store a value other than 0 or 1 in an object of type `_Bool`.

Comment: @exnihilo Another way would be `*(char*)&b = c;`. Or you could play tricks with unions. The specific method doesn't really matter, though.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this guaranteed to work

Yes, booleans in C are just integers, so adding a boolean to an integer is perfectly acceptable under any compiler I know of. C is weakly typed so there is no distinct difference between boolean and integer values. The only significance of a variable declared as `_Bool` is that it automatically converts any value assigned to it to either 1 or 0.

```
_Bool x = 3; //x will be 1
int y = 7;
int z = y + x; //z will be 8
```